# Conectar Excel con ODBC PostgreSql en conexion remota

Tags: postgresql, odbc

estoy intentando conectar desde Excel (a traves de una conexion ODCB PostgreSql), a una base de datos PostgreSql ubicado en un servidor de Base de Datos. Cada vez que intento conectar con el archivo de origen de datos ODBC, me genera el siguiente error: ***"No se puede conectar con el archivo de origen de datos. Razon: acceso denegado. cometio un error al escribir el id. de usuario o contraseña o no tiene acceso al servidor de la base de datos"***
Estoy utilizando un pc con windows 7 y PostgreSql esta en un servidor linux en una red lan.
¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola! Ya configuraste el acceso remoto para la BD?

Comment: Hola,  yo coloque las opciones que me pide el odbc (base de datos, servidor, usuario y clave). ¿hay alguna otra configuración?

Comment: A PostgreSQL, al motor, hay que configurarle para que escuche por interfaces diferentes a localhost y tal. Has probado conectarte a esa misma BD usando un cliente como [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/)?

Comment: Supongo que estás poniendo correctamente la dirección IP del equipo Linux dónde está la BD (¿tiene una IP fija en la red LAN?), así como el puerto correcto, usuario correcto, contraseña correcta, nombre de schema/BD correctos y que, como dice @alfabravo el servidor de BD admite conexiones desde otros sitios.

Comment: Este tipo de conexiones se pueden definir también desde un fichero de configuración, [como explica la documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)